# How to fix errors IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I would like load data which are 10 categories of document, each cateory contains text files, but I keep getting the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

THis is code :

```
def load_data(folder):
data = []
files = [join(folder, x) for x in os.listdir(folder)]
for file in files:
    topic = file.split("/")[9]  # this is where the error occurs
    label = topic.replace(" ", "_")
    name = "__label__" + label
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        content = f.read()
        content = content.decode('utf-16')
        content = " ".join(i for i in content.split())
        data.append(name + " " + content)
return data
```

Comment: Seems like there isn't a 9th element in the list after you split at the "/". Is there a specific reason you want the 9th?

Comment: Hi Van, welcome to StackOverflow! It's hard for us to answer your question until you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Looking at your code now, we're not exactly sure what's passed into your function, and there's a lot of code that doesn't seem to be related to the error. Also, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Can you play around with it a bit more and then [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60878579/edit)?

Comment: jammin0921. I have 10 topic of document examples: sport, health,..  .each topic is a folder. 10 topic want 9 '/' to split

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to debug this would be to add `print` statements and check what the objects hold. For e.g. in this case, you can add 2 `print` statements at the beginning of the `for` loop. This would help you to figure out why you are getting `IndexError`

```
def load_data(folder):
data = []
files = [join(folder, x) for x in os.listdir(folder)]
for file in files:
    print(file)
    print(file.split("/"))
    topic = file.split("/")[9]  # this is where the error occurs
    label = topic.replace(" ", "_")
    name = "__label__" + label
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        content = f.read()
        content = content.decode('utf-16')
        content = " ".join(i for i in content.split())
        data.append(name + " " + content)
return data
```

Comment: I fixed this issues in way remove [9] and  adđ [-1] in line label:  label = topic[-1].replace(" ", "_")